# What are the active records in yii

Tags: yii

I am new with Yii framework , but how the Active records work in Yii, and what are that??

```
How the result will fetch and display all this things.
```

> please explain all Active Records in Yii framework.

help will appriciate.

Comment: go through the official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

Comment: i read all that but how to use conditions and contains array in that.?

Comment: it will be better if you post a question with some code that you have tried and what you want to achieve, its really difficult to answer without knowing the problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity .. ACTIVE RECORD in YII is a ORM. Go through the link .http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar